# subprocess.Popen producing different output than bash

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to conduct a Globus facilitated file transfer via python using the following code:

```
get_task_id = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','gcw8@cli.globusonline.org','"transfer','-s','3','--','ep1#path/to/dir/','ep2#end/point/','-r"'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which produces the error:

```
Command 'transfer -s 3 -- ep1#path/to/dir/ ep2#end/point -r' not found.  Type 'help' for help.
```

This is strange considering I can successfully run:

```
ssh gcw8@cli.globusonline.org "transfer -s 3 -- ep1#path/to/dir/ ep2#end/point/ -r"
```

Which I had understood to be functionally equivalent to the python code above. I realize that Globus transfers are esoteric and most people won't be familiar with the commands given so I'd like to emphasize that my question is more about why my python code is producing a different output than my bash code considering they are supposed to do the same thing.

Comment: Some Globus users recently stumbled across this, so I'd like to make sure that they're aware that we do not encourage the use of subprocess + the CLI for python scripting. In the past year we've been expanding on our [python SDK](http://globus.github.io/globus-sdk-python/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh','gcw8@cli.globusonline.org',
  '"transfer','-s','3','--','ep1#path/to/dir/','ep2#end/point/',
  '-r"'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Is not equivalent to:

```
ssh gcw8@cli.globusonline.org "transfer -s 3 -- ep1#path/to/dir/ ep2#end/point/ -r"
```

You have some odd quotes in your `subprocess.Popen` statement.  I think you want, simply:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'gcw8@cli.globusonline.org', 
  'transfer -s 3 -- ep1#path/to/dir/ ep2#end/point/ -r'])
```

Remember that the shell splits your command into tokens based on whitespace, unless you quote a portion of it.  So your command line ends up getting split into three tokens:

1. `ssh`
2. `gcw8@cli.globusonline.org`
3. `transfer -s 3 -- ep1#path/to/dir/ ep2#end/point/ -r`

So this is exactly what you need to pass to `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: Oh interesting, I wasn't aware that it didn't split by whitespace if a portion was in quotes. This makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Yeah.  For example, consider the output of the shell commands `for word in "this is a test"; do echo $word; done` vs. `for word in this is a test; do echo $word; done`.

Comment: @GWarner: `Popen()` does not run the shell by default and therefore the arguments are passed as is (on POSIX). In addition to not splitting on whitespace, it does not interpret shell variables e.g., `$$` is passed literally to the child process. Unrelated: you could use `output = subprocess.check_output([...])` instead of calling `Popen(..,stdout=PIPE)`  explicitly.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If you set `shell=TRUE` would it interpret shell variables correctly?

Comment: If you set `shell=True` then it will pass the string (not a list) to the shell verbatim, and the shell will do whatever the shell does.  Bascially, you end up with `sh -c "your command here"`.